# recuperar el valor de una sesion con javascript en un <td>

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy queriendo mostrar en consola para trabajar con ese valor, el valor de una `session` que tengo en una tabla la cual genero por una clase .

esta es mi tabla.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >$(function () {    
    var valueQueNecesito = $('#order').text();
    console.log(valueQueNecesito);   
  });</script>------- <?php if ($stat==1): ?>
           <table class='table table- 
   responsive'> 
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope='col'>Nro.Orden</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tdoby>
        <tr>  
          <td id="order"><?= $_SESSION['id_order'];?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Pero no me muestra nada.

Comment: En tu **HTML** no tienes ningún elemento con `#order` así que es normal que al hacer `$('#order').val();` no estés pudiendo mostrar nada en tu `console.log()`

Comment: estuve agregandole al <td> <?= $_SESSION['id_order']; ?></td>  == un  <td id="order"> <?= $_SESSION['id_order']; ?></td> pero tampco me lo recibe, de que manera correcta podria recibirlo ??

Comment: Si lo que quieres es darle el **id** al `<td>` para obtener lo que tiene dentro no puedes hacerlo a través de la función `val()` ya que esta función sirve para obtener el valor de campos como `<input>`, `<textarea>` o `<select>`. Para obtener el texto de un elemento **HTML** podemos usar la función `text()` por lo que tu línea de código debería quedar como esta: `var valueQueNecesito = $('#order').text();`

Comment: tengo el script <script type="text/javascript" >$(function () {    
    var valueQueNecesito = $('#order').text();
    console.log(valueQueNecesito);   
});</script>

Comment: ya lo muestra, muchas gracias phpmyguel